When was the first documented modern practice of Trick or Treating on Halloween?
The origins of Halloween are assumed to be rooted in pagan traditions and the holiday of Samhain.  However during the years the Halloween traditions have become more mainstream and have lost a lot of it's religious connotation.
For instance the modern U.S. cultural practice of going door to door for candy and saying "Trick or treat".
I could not find any ties of this going back to the pagan practices, so I was wondering, what is the first documented instance of this tradition? Where did it stem from?
The Wikipedia link that T.E.D. provided is informative, it is too broad for my question. I also think this question which is properly scoped and on-topic for this site has value as would its answer if provided.

Love the question, particularly since its seasonal. I do have to verify that the Wikipedia Page on the history of trick-or-treating doesn't answer your question?

No I do not believe that link satisfactorily answers my question.

Did you follow the source links for the The interjection "Trick or treat!" section of the Wikipedia page that T.E.D. linked to? In particular, the OED article on the interjection gives four newspaper sources.

We do not know it is rooted in Samhain.  In fact, we know it is not, and that it is impossible that it is.  The feast of All Saints' Day (All Hallows' Day), in April, was older than the evangelization of Ireland, and the practice of putting it in November was German, not Irish, in origin.

I have edited the question.
